# Adding Text to a Photoshop Created Layout

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I created and exported a layout in Photoshop; the results are here. How do I now add text on top of this layout? My  tag is adding it below the layout rather than on top of it, and the WYSIWYG tools are not especially great.

ETA: I'm aware that exporting like this from Photoshop isn't ideal. However, it was required for a class assignment.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>DarkLayout</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<style>
div.text {
width:250px;
padding:269px;
border:0px;
margin:10px;
color: #39376f;
opacity: 0.5; 
}

p{
    font-family:"Letter Gothic Std Bold";
    font-size: 18 pt;
    color: #39376f;
}
</style>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (DarkLayout.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="955" height="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="images/DarkLayout_01.gif" width="955" height="120" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="10">
            <img src="images/DarkLayout_02.gif" width="38" height="480" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/DarkLayout_03.gif" width="166" height="66" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="10">
            <img src="images/DarkLayout_04.gif" width="751" height="480" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <div.text>
<p> Here is some demo font.</p></div.text>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/DarkLayout_05.gif" width="166" height="30" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/DarkLayout_06.gif" width="166" height="66" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/DarkLayout_07.gif" width="166" height="27" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/DarkLayout_08.gif" width="164" height="66" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="4">
            <img src="images/DarkLayout_09.gif"width="2" height="176" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/DarkLayout_10.gif" width="164" height="22" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/DarkLayout_11.gif" width="164" height="66" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/DarkLayout_12.gif"width="164" height="22" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/DarkLayout_13.gif" width="166" height="66" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/DarkLayout_14.gif" width="166" height="49" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is this  <div.text> ?

Comment: This is a horrible approach, don't just export it as a table from Photoshop. You want to code it up using HTML divs and CSS.

Comment: I didn't have a choice on this one; it's for a class taught through my university and this was the expectation.

Answer (score 1):

It has obviously been stated that this is not the method to go for, and in any other case you should definitely code it using HTML and CSS, but considering this is for a class and there's no choice, here's an answer:

When adding an image through the `<img src>` tag, you're basically creating another div (or box) to your layout, meaning that you can't easily put anything on top of it.

If you can actually play with the code you got after using Photoshop, I'd instead add the image as a background image to your `td` tag, like so:

`<td rowspan="10" background="images/DarkLayout_04.gif" width="" height=""><p> Here is some demo font.</p></td>`

Basically, what you are doing is setting the `td`'s background to be an image, and that allows you to write on top of it. The same could be achieved by setting a div's background image, instead of an `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Never use things such as export layout to html, because it will create a really messy and buggy structures - in this example you have everything in tables, while tables should be only used for tabular data only.

If you plan on making more websites in future, you'll save lots of time by learning html and css. Internet is full of free resources, articles, videos etc.

Comment: This was actually for my CSS class through university, so I didn't have a choice.